# VPS vs Dedicated server, security- and performance-wise

Tags: security, performance, vps, dedicated-server

I've been search the web for information and advice on the whole "VPS vs Dedicated"-question.
All I can find on the subject is based on economy and a bit performance.

So here goes: What are the pros and cons when considering a change from dedicated server to VPS, or even the other way around?

The server hosts multiple webapplications using SQL Server 2012 and IIS 7.5.

The server is being accessed through Remote Desktop, FileZilla Server and SQL Server Management Studio (SQL Server Authentication).

Furthermore it hosts a SMTP-server through MailEnable to be used in the webapplications.

The Windows Firewall is scoping IP connectivity to SQL Server and FileZilla FTP and a lot of ports have been closed down, to strengthen security.

**Hardware-aspects (performance-wise)**

```
Dedicated server: 
- Capacity-limited RAM
- Capacity-limited HDD-space
- Capacity-limited CPUs


VPS:
- Unlimited RAM
- Unlimited HDD-space
- Up to a number of CPUs (typical 24?)
```

**Security-aspects**

To my knowledge, the local files and SQL Server data are as secure as it gets on the dedicated server. Is this an issue on a VPS?

Some of the files are containing private information (salary, social security numbers, and more) on the users the webapplications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The security aspect comes down to who controls the physical machine that the virtual machine is hosted on. If it's not you, then do you *trust* the host? Because the host has access to all that information unless you encrypt it otherwise.

If it's you, then it's as secure as the box the virtual machine is hosted on (VPS = VM after all). The unlimited aspects are actually limited by the resources available on the actual machine the VPS is hosted on.

Comment: The physical machine, where VPS or dedicated, are being hosted by a professional hosting company, which we trust. The question is more; if using a VPS, is it anyhow possible for OTHERS VPS servers on the same server, to access our local files? :)

Comment: No, the VPSs are isolated from each other.

Comment: So, there is actually absolutely no point in having a dedicated server today, because the VPS are so evolved? They are easier to upgrade hardware-wise and cheaper to host?

Comment: Not exactly. Dedicated servers are *much* more powerful than a VPS because on a VPS you're sharing hardware with other users. Some hosting companies will "oversell" resources which can slow things down a bit. Plus, upgrades can be limited depending on your host.

However, dedicated servers are certainly something you only want if you need dedicated hardware for an application. Otherwise, a VPS or cloud hosting will work fine.

Comment: Plus there are some things you can't (easily) do with a virtual server, such as attach an RS232 GSM modem (for sending SMSes directly), or a USB entropy source.

Comment: Brilliant, Thanks Nathan C! And thanks MadHatter for the extra info :)

Comment: Yeah. It is about scalability. VPS is good for small / mid load, and today that goes quite high (Hyper-V: 32 virtual cores). But there is a time you have  VM using up all of a machine...

Comment: @nathanc so a VPS provider CAN access the data somehow?

Comment: @HerrK Yes, they can if they really want to.